# Evaluation of expectation of integral with random variable in its bound

Tags: integration, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, expected-value, stochastic-integrals

I am in the following setting.

> Let $$Y_T =\int^{X_T}_0\frac{1}{\sigma(x)}dx$$
>   where $dX_t = \sigma(X_t)dW_t$, with $W_t$ a regular Brownian motion and $\sigma$
>   an arbitrary positive function. Moreover, we have that $\mathbb{E}[X_T]=0$ ($X_t$ is a martingale).

The problem I am now facing is that I have to find $\mathbb{E}[Y_T]$.

I am not sure how to approach the problem, or if it is even solvable in the current state of the given information, but I attempted the following (very sketchy) solution

$$Y_T =\int^{X_T}_0\frac{1}{\sigma(x)}dx = \int^{X_T}_0\frac{1}{\sigma(x)}\sigma(x)dW=\int^{X_T}_0 dW$$

Which would mean that the expectation is zero. I have a feeling, though, that what I am doing is not allowed.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Could you compute $dY_T = fdt + gdW$ then $d\mathbb{E}[Y_T] = \mathbb{E}[f]dt$

Comment: @gt6989b The dynamics for $Y_t$ that I have are of the form $dY_t = dW_t + f(Y_t)dt$. However, where would I use this $d\mathbb{E}[Y_T]$ that you mention?

Comment: Your problem defines $Y_T = f(X_T)$ where $f$ is the integral in question. Can you please apply Ito's Lemma to $Y_T$ and plug in the dynamics of $X_T$ which are given. Maybe I am missing something, but I don't see how the dynamics you just wrote in the previous comment would arize from such an exercise. Can you please update your question with that result, and then we will go from there.

Comment: @gt6989b Sorry for the confusion. The problem I described above is a simplified version of what the problem actually is, so I might have oversimplified it to the point that it doesn't make sense anymore. Anyway, with your tip I get $$dY_T = \frac{1}{\sigma(X_T)}dX_T$$ which I can work out to find $dY_T = dW_T$ by using the dynamics of $X_t$. I know the expectation of a Brownian motion is zero, but how exactly do I conclude $\mathbb{E}[Y_T]=0$ from $dY_T = dW_T$? What rule gets used here?

Comment: You now have $$Y_t = Y_0 + \int_0^T dY_t = Y_0 + \int_0^T dW_t = Y_0 + W_T$$ but I think it is not that simple. You may have forgotten the second-order term in Ito's lemma

Comment: @gt6989b Fair enough, I'll take a look again but I think this is the right approach. Thanks alot.